# How to add MyServiceInterceptor class to networkmodule using dagger hilt android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-hilt

I need to add MyServiceInterceptor class to my hilt servicemodule for different request.
for example my login request don't need header authorize but my other request needs bearer token.

My question is how can i add this ? Any help please ?

**My Networking Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object NetworkingModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(): String {
        return NetworkingConstants.BASE_URL
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }




    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()

        okHttpClient.callTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        okHttpClient.build()
        return okHttpClient.build()
    }



    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory(): Converter.Factory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitClient(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, baseUrl: String, converterFactory: Converter.Factory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRestApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

**And MyServiceInterceptorClass**

```
@Singleton
public class MyServiceInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val preferencesHelper: PreferencesHelper
) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var newRequest: Request = chain.request()

        newRequest = newRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader(
                "AccessToken",
                preferencesHelper.getAccessTokenFromPreference()!!
            )
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)

    }
}
```

Comment: There are different ways to do this before using Hilt or Dagger .. which approach you follow? So I can think of how to make hilt help you in this (if needed at all).

Comment: I get token from login request. And other all request will use this token.(bearer token)

Comment: No no, I meant, if you won't use Dependency Injection at all .. which way you will use to solve this problem. There are solutions for this without the need of Hilt I read somewhere in stackoverflow .. Or you are asking how to solve it using Retrofit?

Comment: can you provide example of the two request objects that are required to be processed.
And meanwhile, you can check about Qualifiers in dagger.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use qualifiers in order to add your service interceptor class in your network module. Here is a working example.

First of all, create a class qualifiers.kt and define your annotation there for your service class

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ApiKeyInterceptorOkHttpClient
```

You can make your separate class for Interceptor as follow:

```
class ApiKeyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val original: Request = chain.request()
        val httpUrl: HttpUrl = original.url
        val url: HttpUrl = httpUrl.newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("api_key", BuildConfig.API_KEY)
            .build()
        val request: Request = original.newBuilder().url(url).build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Then, in your network module, you can then provide your interceptor

```
@ApiKeyInterceptorOkHttpClient
@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesApiKeyInterceptor(): Interceptor = ApiKeyInterceptor()
```

Finally you can use your interceptor in your Okhttp Client.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesOkhttpClient(
     httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
     @ApiKeyInterceptorOkHttpClient apiKeyInterceptor: Interceptor) =
     OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
         .addInterceptor(apiKeyInterceptor)
         .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .build()
```

Comment: I think you need to replace  `=` with `: OkHttpClient {
        return ...`

Answer (score -1):

```
@Provides
fun providesLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
    return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
}


@Provides
fun providesOkhttpInterceptor() : Interceptor{
    return  Interceptor { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val original: Request = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder: Request.Builder = original.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON")
        val request: Request = requestBuilder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
}


@Provides
fun providesOkHttpClient(
    loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
    interceptor: Interceptor
): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution that the user asked.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [@Qualifier](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#multiple-bindings) annotation.